What happens when there are dangerous animals in the teeing area?
Rule 16.2 of the rules of golf provides relief from dangerous animals on the course

A “dangerous animal condition” exists when a dangerous animal (such as venomous snakes, stinging bees, alligators, fire ants or bears) near a ball could cause serious physical injury to the player if they had to play the ball as it lies.
A player may take relief under
Rule 16.2b
from interference by a dangerous animal condition no matter where their ball is on the course.

Rule 16.2b provides the procedure for relief for 4 of the 5 course areas, but doesn’t mention a procedure for the teeing area(which makes sense, because your ball is not “in” the teeing area until you put it there), and Rule 6 doesn’t mention anything about dangerous animals.
What should be done if dangerous animals prevent access to the teeing area?
This is not merely a hypothetical question for me, these 2 pictures were taken in the same solo round, and I wouldn’t be going this close to adult males in any other circumstances.



Unlucky outing, yes?
